# How do I emulate key function CTRL-B to a barcode

Tags: ascii, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing, code128

This is my first post on this website, can't seem to  solve the problem.

How do I emulate key function <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to a barcode so i can scan the barcode with a scanner without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.
I've tried reading the ASCII Control Codes [ASCII control codes](https://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/ascii_ctrl.htm)
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one of your tags demonstrates, you are already aware of the code 128 symbology. You will want to use the code128A start code (103) and the same character as a lower case 'b' in code128B (66). Finally, after adding additional data, properly calculate the checksum and add it as well as the stop code (106). The following HTML illustrates:

```html
<img 
alt="103,{Start A}" title="103,{Start A}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AC9gAMEAkBQ+aMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="40"><img
alt=" 66,A:{STX},B:{b}" title=" 66,A:{STX},B:{b}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AG8gAQEAkGqGy8gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="40"><img
alt=" 52,A:{T},B:{T}" title=" 52,A:{T},B:{T}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ACOgAOkAxNCxwt0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="40"><img
alt=" 37,A:{E},B:{E}" title=" 37,A:{E},B:{E}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AHLgAccBU7KPeu8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="40"><img
alt=" 51,A:{S},B:{S}" title=" 51,A:{S},B:{S}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ACLgAScBA3yI80wAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="40"><img
alt=" 52,A:{T},B:{T}" title=" 52,A:{T},B:{T}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ACOgAOkAxNCxwt0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="40"><img
alt=" 24,A:{8},B:{8}" title=" 24,A:{8},B:{8}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ABZgAI8Ad3Mh6bwAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="40"><img
alt="106,{Stop}"title="106,{Stop}"src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAABAQMAAAA/57ZEAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADigARMA2dpJzT8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="20" height="40">
```

To test, open up Wordpad or any word processor that uses 'Ctrl-B' to switch bold text on and off. Scan a printed copy of the barcode in the snippet. You should see the text "TEST" alternate between bold and plain styles each time you scan.

```html
<img 
alt="103,{Start A}" title="103,{Start A}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AC9gAMEAkBQ+aMgAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="12" height="33"><img
alt=" 66,A:{STX},B:{b}" title=" 66,A:{STX},B:{b}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AG8gAQEAkGqGy8gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="12" height="33"><img
alt=" 66,A:{STX},B:{b}" title=" 66,A:{STX},B:{b}" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAABAQMAAAAy+cYDAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/AG8gAQEAkGqGy8gAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="12" height="33"><img
alt="106,{Stop}"title="106,{Stop}"src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAA0AAAABAQMAAAA/57ZEAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAADklEQVQIHQEDAPz/ADigARMA2dpJzT8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=" width="12" height="33">
```

Comment: how do i remove the "test" text?

Comment: The HTML is constructed as 8 <img> tags. It turns out that the checksum character for a 'Ctrl-B' is also a 'Ctrl-B' (66). So, for the 9 lines in the snippet, keep lines 1 (opening <img), 2 (103), and 3 (66), remove the lines that spell out TEST and the checksum (8), copy line 3 (66) and paste it in right below 3 making it 4 (66) and the stop line that was 9 (106) stays and becomes line 5.