# How do I emulate SHIFT+10 and ALT+F4 to a barcode

Tags: html, ascii, barcode

can somone share the method of how to create an image without the start and stop code please of 128A barcode ?

i need to create a barcode for SHIFT+F10 and ALT+F4

i followed this topic to get help

[How To Emulate CTRL+B Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45222061/how-do-i-emulate-key-function-ctrl-b-to-a-barcode)

Thanks for your help

Comment: You first need to attempt to solve the problem and then approach us with a SPECIFIC question if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

All a barcode can give you is ASCII characters (Ctrl-i, Ctrl-c, Ctrl-f, etc.). You don't want ASCII characters, you are asking for keyCodes which cannot be represented by 8-bit ASCII. 128A barcodes also do not work without the calculated checksum. I don't think it is possible to do whatever you are attempting.